# Finding continuity with records that denote periods

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, recursive-query

I have a table that expresses periods of responsibility, similar to the following:

```
Key     Resp_Key      Start_Date      End_Date
1       150           2015-01-01      2015-01-25
2       150           2015-01-25      2015-02-15
3       200           2015-02-15      2015-03-01
4       150           2015-03-01      2015-04-30
5       150           2015-04-30      NULL
```

When someone is currently responsible, the column `End_Date` is `NULL`. For the above instance, the party with `Resp_Key` 150 has been responsible since March 1st (other columns may have changed on April 30th which caused another record to be created for that date, but those aren't important for this question).

I need to create a query that finds all continuous records that are connected to the current period and `Resp_Key`. In the above example, the query should return records 4 and 5, since record 5 is the current period, and record 4 is connected to it (since record 4's `End_Date` is the `Start_Date` of record 5, and they both have the same `Resp_Key`). Record 3 wouldn't be included, since `Resp_Key` is different, and records 1 and 2 wouldn't be included either, since they aren't continuous from the current record.

If the following changes/additions are made:

```
Key     Resp_Key      Start_Date      End_Date
5       150           2015-04-30      2015-05-31
6       231           2015-05-31      2015-06-30
7       150           2015-06-30      NULL
```

the query should return only record 7, since it's the current record, and the period immediately preceding it has a different `Resp_Key`.

I've been trying to compose a CTE to handle this, but I'm not sure that's the correct tool. A recursive CTE would make sense, since I can't tell beforehand how many records are part of the continuous period I'm interested in. But the CTE I composed is telling me that LEFT JOINs can't be used, and I don't see how to get around the need for it for the case where there's only one record making the latest continuous period.

```
;WITH ContinuousPeriod
AS (
    -- Current Period and key of immediately preceding period
    SELECT Current.Key, Current.Start_Date, Current.End_Date, Previous.Key AS PrevKey
    FROM PeriodTable AS Current
    LEFT JOIN PeriodTable AS Previous
        ON Previous.End_Date = Current.Start_Date
        AND Previous.Resp_Key = Current.Resp_Key
    WHERE Current.PEVNT_END_DATE IS NULL    
    UNION ALL
    . . .
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Sql server 2012+` then you can use `LEAD/LAG` window function to check the continuity

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT [key], 
                resp_key, 
                start_date, 
                end_date, 
                lag_ed=Lag(end_date)OVER(partition BY resp_key 
                           ORDER BY start_date) 
         FROM   test) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  start_date = lag_ed 
        OR end_date IS NULL
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c795/5)

If you are using sql server 2008 or lesser then you need to generate row number for each `resp_key` then self the join the result to check the continuity

Comment: I'm working on the variant you describe for someone stuck in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is to find where sequences of consecutive times begin.  This occurs when the `lag()` of the start date is not appropriate.  You then want all records after the last of these.  So:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             lag(end_date) over (partition by resp_key order by start_date) as prev_end_date
      from test t
      where resp_key = (select resp_key from test t where end_date is null)
     ),
     tt as (
      select resp_key, max(start_date) as last_sequence_start
      from t
      where prev_end_date is null or prev_end_date <> start_date
      group by resp_key
     )
select t.*
from test t join
     tt
     on tt.resp_key = t.resp_key
where t.start_date >= tt.last_sequence_start;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c795/8) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I hadn't heard of the LAG function, and it looks like it would solve my problem, if I weren't stuck in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, I believe you can use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.100).aspx) instead which is supported in SQL Server 2008 like below:

```
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT [Key]
        ,Resp_Key
        ,Start_Date
        ,End_Date
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY Resp_Key ORDER BY Start_Date
            ) as rn
    FROM test
    )
SELECT 
     cte.[Key]
    ,cte.Resp_Key
    ,cte.Start_Date
    ,cte.End_Date
FROM cte 
join cte c1 on c1.start_date = cte.end_date 
            and c1.rn= cte.rn+1 
            and c1.end_date is null
 UNION ALL
 select 
     cte.[Key]
    ,cte.Resp_Key
    ,cte.Start_Date
    ,cte.End_Date
 from cte 
 where cte.end_date is null
 order by cte.Resp_Key,cte.Start_Date;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c795/4/0)